# Restrict users report for particular routes using Embed API

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, url-routing, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to restrict the users to view the reports with respect to particular routes assigned for an application using Embed API?

> Ex : User-X should have a privilege to check all the traffic coming to
>   the route **www.dummy.com/test** and not for **www.dummy.com/test1**
>   and check the users details everything related to this route

Comment: Yeah i understand, what if we store some relevant details of the particular role user and send the required page in scope?

Comment: OK,  using the embed api, you might be able to add some filters to restrict there access.    But remember in order for them to see your site in the embed api you must first give them access to your Google Analytics account which means they could then just use the website to view everything.

Comment: Then their is a chance of leakage of data, may i know the best way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Extract the data into your own database and display the info to the users from there.

Comment: The response is an JavaScript object, their could be a chance of hack in the middle of it if the user is technical savvy if am not wrong and also this is an realtime scenario

Comment: Data in the Google Analytics and the API isn't done processing for between 24-48 hours so its not really real-time.   The Real-time API is very limited to what data you can see, so if you truly are only checking the real-time data then maybe it wont be as big of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view that only includes allowed data and give the user read permissions only for this view. Of course that it a) a lot of work and b) rather limits the possible number of users.

For any practical purpose the answer would be "no, use a serverside API and do your filtering there".